# $emit is not emitting the message to parent from inside axios

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component, axios

I have a method in child component which is responsible to get the data from server and after receiving the data, i am trying to emit the data to parent. The below method is from Vue.component (child). The problem is, parent component is not able to receive the emitted data. Just to check, I moved the $emit code outside axios request call, then it is working. If i $emit from inside axios, it is not working.

Not working (emit from inside axios):

```
methods:{
    methodName: function(){
        let self = this;
        axios.get('url')
        .then(function(response){
            if (response.data.res) {
                console.log('response is true, i can see this message');
                self.$emit('updateparentdata',response.data);
            }
        });
        self.$emit('close');
    }
},
```

Working (emit from outside axios):

```
methods:{
    methodName: function(){
        let self = this;
        self.$emit('updateparentdata','some dummy data');
        axios.get('url')
        .then(function(response){
            if (response.data.res) {

            }
        });
        self.$emit('close');
    }
},
```

This is my component code in my html page, if something is emitted from updateparentdata, then it will call 'updateData' function in parent vue.

```
<modal 
    v-if="showModal"
    @close="showModal = false"
    v-on:updateparentdata="updateData">
</modal>
```

This is my method in parent vue,

```
updateData: function(response){
    console.log(response);
},
```

This method is not triggered after i emitted the data from child component. If i emit data outside axios, then this method is called, but if i emit data from inside axios, this method is not called.

Comment: Are you sure that `response.data.res` is `true`?

Comment: Yes, i checked it with console.log message. response.data.res is true. I modified my code with console.log statement, can you pls check it. @thanksd

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue. See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nxcne6zr/

Comment: I figured out what was the problem and provided the fix below. Thanks for your contribution. @thanksd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vue.nextTick to wait for updates.

Try this inside axios :

```
this.$nextTick(() => {
  self.$emit('close');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, please see my solution below. @Matija

Answer (score 4):

Thanks for your answers.

I found what the problem is, I was calling $emit('close') function outside axios call.

Since axios call is asynchronous, after making the request, $emit('close') which is outside axios instance actually closes my modal window which removes my whole component instance.

Thats why this $emit('updateparentdata') function inside axios call was not worked performed as expected.

**Solution 1:**

I moved the $emit('close') inside axios request, so after receiving the response I am closing the modal window.

```
methods:{
    methodName: function(){
        let self = this;
        axios.get('url')
        .then(function(response){
            if (response.data.res) {
                console.log('response is true, i can see this message');
                self.$emit('updateparentdata',response.data);
                self.$emit('close');
            }
        });
    }
},
```

**Solution 2:**

As mentioned by @Matija Župančić, I tried with Vue.nextTick to wait for the updates. This method also worked.

Comment: Thanks for this, I did the same thing! My emit inside axios.finally was never reaching the parent component because the child component was being removed due to a v-if on it

Answer (score 0):

as @RubanrajRavichandran mentioned in his Solution 1 where `self = this` its because in the axios .then the this changes.  you can instead use arrow function like `.then((response) => {}` and `this` will work so you don't have to use `self`